# How import local OsmAnd library in Android Studio?

Tags: android, osmand

I want to download and import local version of OsmAnd library in Android Studio.

I work correctly with the aar, but I need to download and use the library locally:

```
implementation "net.osmand:OsmAnd-java:master-snapshot:android@jar"

debugImplementation "net.osmand:OsmAnd:master-snapshot:debug@aar"
releaseImplementation "net.osmand:OsmAnd:master-snapshot:release@aar"

implementation "net.osmand:antpluginlib:3.8.0@aar"

debugImplementation "net.osmand:MPAndroidChart:custom-snapshot-debug@aar"
releaseImplementation "net.osmand:MPAndroidChart:custom-snapshot-release@aar"

implementation "net.osmand:OsmAndCore_androidNativeRelease:master-snapshot@aar"
implementation "net.osmand:OsmAndCore_android:master-snapshot@aar"
```

I'm a newbie, so a detailed answer (like step by step) is better if possible, thanks!

I tried reading generic answers about importing libraries in Android Studio but no success.